# Is the motion of a billiard ball time reversal invariant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, collision, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider the motion of a billiard ball on two different billiard boards. One board is frictionless and another is not. The magnitude of the friction force of board on the ball is proportional to the speed of the ball. The force is directed opposite to the velocity of the ball.

"The motion of the billiard ball on the frictionless table is time-reversal invariant. But the motion of the ball on the board with friction is not".

Is the previous statement correct?

Comment: it is correct if the collisions are elastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks so, if

- we deal with **one ball only**,
- all the **collisions** with the wall are perfectly **elastic**

For non-elastic collisions with the wall, even with the frictionless table the problem is not time-reversal invariant. With many balls, thermodynamics appear and entropy would play a role in showing you the direction of time.

Let's prove it with a linear model for friction.

### Linear friction

Using a simple model of friction $\mathbf{F}_{\mu} = - \mu \mathbf{\dot{x}}$, focusing on the in-plane motion between two collisions, so that the dynamics is governed by
\begin{equation}
  m \ddot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{F}_{\mu} \ .
\end{equation}

Let's check if this equation is invariant to the transformation of time $t \rightarrow -t$, $t'(t) = -t$.

The second order time derivative reads
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \mathbf{x} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{d}{dt}  \mathbf{x} \right) =  \underbrace{\dfrac{d t'}{d t}}_{=-1} \dfrac{d}{d t'} \left( \underbrace{\dfrac{d t'}{d t}}_{=-1} \dfrac{d}{dt'} \mathbf{x} \right) = \dfrac{d^2 \mathbf{x}}{d t'^2} \ ,
\end{equation}
while the first derivative in friction force becomes
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbf{x} = \underbrace{\dfrac{d t'}{d t}}_{=-1} \dfrac{d \mathbf{x}}{dt'} = - \dfrac{d \mathbf{x}}{dt'} \ .
\end{equation}

It should be easy to verify that the two equations with $t$ or $t'$ as the independent time variable reads
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \text{direct  :} & \qquad m \ddot{\mathbf{x}} = -\mu \dot{\mathbf{x}} \\
  \text{indirect:} & \qquad  m \mathbf{x}'' = \mu \mathbf{x}' \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

### Integration: no friction

With no friction, integration of these equations provides constant uniform motion
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{x}(t) & = \mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{v}_0 t \\
  \mathbf{x}(t') & = \mathbf{x}'_0 + \mathbf{v'}_0 t' \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where you can't distinguish the "right" direction of time

### Integration: friction

With frictions, the solution of the dynamical equations reads
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{x}(t) & = \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{c} \exp\left(-\dfrac{\mu t}{m}\right) \\
  \mathbf{x'}(t') & = \mathbf{a'} + \mathbf{c'} \exp\left(\dfrac{\mu t'}{m}\right)  \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
Thus,

- in the right direction of time, the point decelerates exponentially due to friction;
- in the opposite direction of time, the point accelerates exponentially.
  We can easily distinguish these two situations, and recognize that only the motion in the right direction of time is feasible.

Comment: Just confirming: t'(t) = -t. And the statement above is correct.

Comment: You're right. Typo in copy and paste, while cooking

Comment: so, if you're ok with the answer, upvoting and acceptung is the way to do